# Functions that has finite support

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The support of a function is defined as
$$\operatorname{supp}(f) := \{n \in\mathbb N | f(n) \neq 0\}$$ 
A function $f$ has finite support if $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is a finite set.

We know that the support of a function $f$ is a subset of the domain of the function $f$. In the case of a function $f$ has finite support, the $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is a finite set and $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is a subset of the domain of $f$.

Can we say that if $\vert\operatorname{supp}(f)\vert = \vert\operatorname{Domain}(f)\vert$ then $f(n)$ is finite?

And if $\vert\operatorname{supp}(f)\vert < \vert\operatorname{Domain}(f)\vert$, can we say that $f(n)$ is a bijection?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is quite confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we say that if |*supp (f)*| = |*Domain (f)*|, *f(n)* is finite?

This question is very confused. First of all, if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, then for every $n$, the number $f(n)$ is an element of $\mathbb N$, and therefore finite.

Second of all, as far as I see in your example, the domain of $f$ is always $\mathbb N$, meaning that $|Domain(f)| = |\mathbb N| = \aleph_0$.

Finally, if $|supp(f)|<|Domain(f)|$, and $\mathrm {Domain} f = \mathbb N$, we can **prove** that $f$ is not a bijection, because it is obviously not injective.

Comment: The domain of f is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @Jas Then my answer does not need correcting. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes @5xum. Thank you! I'm now wondering if a function whose support is finite is also finite? Maybe, I'll post it as a question later.

Comment: @jas What does it mean for a function to be finite?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to said the image set of the function. Thx.

Comment: @Jas Then yes, if a function has finite support, then the image is finite.

Comment: thank you! can you send some reference about support functions in general.